# removing deplicate entries based on first column and keeping the latest entry, using Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

i need some perl code for the following problem. thanks in advance for your efforts.

my input is in a file in this format: 'name'    'version number'

---

```
tech-sgla-zustand-ts.ini    1.1
tech-sgla-zustand-ts-feld.ini    1.1
tech-sgla-stamm-cds-feld.ini    1.1
tech-sgla-zustand-ts-feld.ini    1.2
tech-sgla-zustand-ts-feld.ini    1.4
tech-sgla-zustand-ts-feld.ini    1.3
```

---

i need it in the format (without blank lines in between):
the 'name' should be unique with maximum 'version number'

---

```
tech-sgla-zustand-ts.ini    1.1
tech-sgla-zustand-ts-feld.ini    1.4
tech-sgla-stamm-cds-feld.ini    1.1
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
open(TOUT, "temp.txt");
while($line = <TOUT>){
    my ($ini, $vers) = split / +/, $line;
    print "ini $ini  vers $vers";
    if (exists $iniFiles{$ini}) {
        $iniFiles{$ini} = $vers if ($iniFiles{$ini} < $vers);
    }
    else {
        $iniFiles{$ini} = $vers;
    }
}
print "\n";
while (my ($k,$v) = each %iniFiles) {
    print "$k  $v";
    $ssldata = $k . "    " . $v;
}
```

Thanks OMG_peanuts for ur responce, but i needed to modify it a little bit to get it working according to my requirement.
Thanks to eugene y as well for ur responce.

Answer (score 1):

If the output order doesn't matter you can use this one-liner:

```
perl -ane '$h{$F[0]} = $F[1] if $F[1] > $h{$F[0]};
 END { print "$_ $h{$_}\n" for keys %h }' file
```

Otherwise this script should do it:

```
my (%h, @a);

while (<>) {
    my ($name, $ver) = split;
    push @a, $name unless exists $h{$name};        
    $h{$name} = $ver if $ver > $h{$name} ; 
}

print "$_ $h{$_}\n" for @a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
my %iniFiles = ();
while (<>) {
  my ($ini, $vers) = split / +/, $_;
  if (exists $iniFiles{$ini}) {
    $iniFiles{$ini} = $vers if ($iniFiles{$ini} < $vers);
  } else { $iniFiles{$ini} = $vers }
}
while (my ($k,$v) = each %iniFiles) { print "$k $v\n" }
```

Or if the input order is important :

```
my @inis = ();
my %iniFiles = ();
while (<>) {
  my ($ini, $vers) = split / +/, $_;
  if (exists $iniFiles{$ini}) {
    $iniFiles{$ini} = $vers if ($iniFiles{$ini} < $vers);
  } else { push @inis, $ini; $iniFiles{$ini} = $vers }
}
foreach (@inis) { print "$_ $iniFiles{$_}\n" }
```